# Dynamically change the position of popover window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `div` of `buttons` which is shows up when you click on the an article. But I am having difficulty to confine this popover window in my article `div`, as currently if you click on the edge of the article -> the popover buttons are not displayed correctly as you can imagine.

JSfiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/kpfax14n/35/

```
  $('.tweets_pane').mouseup(function(event) {
    console.log("Mouse up");
    if (!getRightClick(event) ){
      console.log("Show buttons");
      $('.entity_types').css({
        display: 'block',
        position: 'absolute',
        left: (event.pageX+10) + 'px',
        top: (event.pageY+15) + 'px'
      });
    }
  });
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not very good to imagine. Please share a fiddle

Comment: Hi there, I have added a jfiddle in the question but somehow the popover doesn't appear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to compare the `window.width` to your div width

```
var left_value = event.pageX+10,
    window_width = $(window).width();
console.log('left_value = ' +left_value + ' | '+ 'window_width = '+ window_width);
    if ((left_value + 290) > window_width){ // 280 = 250px (width) + 6px (borders) + 24px (padding) + 10 (for extreme)
    left_value = window_width - 320;
  }
  $('.entity_types').css({
    display: 'block',
    position: 'absolute',
    left: left_value + 'px',
    top: (event.pageY+15) + 'px'
  });
```

[Updated Fiddle V2](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/kpfax14n/42/)

*The original fiddle wasn't working cause you forgot to add jQuery*

**Edit** : For the height too.

Comment: Thanks very much @Core972 ! How do you suggest to adjust the height of the popover window dynamically? When the text at the bottom of the article is selected, the window should still appears in the article. I tried `$(window).height()` but couldn't figure it out..

Comment: Also thanks for pointing out the missing of jQuery. I have added it now to the jsfiddle in the question. Currently if I select text at the end of first article, the popover window blocks the view of the 2nd article.